# Identify Links to Assets Across Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, links

I am working at removing content from a Sharepoint site. It has to due with a discontinued product. I can find most of the hosted documents that relate to the product through search, but am trying to identify the hyperlinks that link to these files across the site. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do You need to find all links, that are used internally in one item about other?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand. I can find documents (PDFs, Word Docs, etc.), that I must remove, but I also want to find the links that people would use to navigate to these documents on the front end.